# Meteor MongoDB pub/sub memory error

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm doing data visualizations using Meteor, running React and D3 for the view. Today decided to populate the MongoDB server with more documents (a total of 30 documents, netting ~50k lines each). There was no issue before running the database with 'only' 4 documents, but now I'm seeing

```
Exception while polling query {"collectionName":"Metrics","selector":{},"options":{"transform":null}}: MongoError: Query exceeded the maximum allowed memory usage of 40 MB. Please consider adding more filters to reduce the query response size.
```

This is my collections.js file, because autopublish is **off**.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {    
    const remoteCollectionString = "notForHumanConsumption";
    database = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver(remoteCollectionString);

    Meteor.publish('metricsDB', function() {
        return Metrics.find({})
    });
}

Metrics = new Mongo.Collection("Metrics", { _driver: database });

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.startup(function() {
        Session.set('data_loaded', false); 
        console.log(Session.get('data_loaded'))
    }); 

    Meteor.subscribe('metricsDB', function(){
        // Set the reactive session as true to indicate that the data have been loaded
        Session.set('data_loaded', true); 
        console.log(Session.get('data_loaded'))
    });
}
```

Adding any type of `sort` in the publish function seems to at least get the console to log `true`, but it does so pretty much instantly. The terminal shows no error, but I'm stuck and not getting any data to the App.

**Update**: decided to remove 10 entries from the collection, limiting it to 20, and now the collection is **~28MB** large, instead of **~42MB** for the 30 items. The App is loading, albeit slowly.

The data structure looks pretty much like this:

```
{
    _id: BLAKSBFLUyiy79a6fs9Pjhadkh&SA86886Daksh, 
    DateQueried: dateString,
    DataSet1: [
        {
            ID,
            Name,
            Properties: [
                {
                    ID,
                    Name,
                    Nr,
                    Status: [0, 1, 2, 3], 
                    LocationData: { 
                        City,
                        CountryCode,
                        PostalCode,
                        Street,
                        StreetNumber
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    DataSet2: [ 
        {
            ID,
            Name,
            Nr,
            Obj: {
                NrR,
                NrGS,
                LengthOfR
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In each document DataSet1 is usually 9 items long. Properties in there can contain up to ~1900 (they average around 500) items. DataSet2 is normally around 49 items.

Comment: 50k lines of what - json or text? Maybe you need to compress the data?

Comment: JSON, so that's including the structure `{...[...]}` etc. The database with 30 documents is **~42MB**. Currently reduced to **~28MB** as we've removed 10 entries and are now left with 20 of them, which makes the app at least launch again. Still, it slow as all hell. How would compressing work?

Keeping in mind that I'd eventually have a year's worth of entries, with one new entry added daily. At this moment that looks like a mission impossible. I want to do data manipulation / restructuring client side, to give users the option to play with visualization as much as they'd want.

Comment: @Casimir how is the document structured, that it gets up to 50k lines? Are ALL PARTS of the document required to be loaded immediately or could you lazy-load the data? This could reduce your query size a lot. In my app for example, I normalized all my data because it became so big and complex. Now I load way smaller data sets, referencing each other by `_id` and allowing a smooth ui (because of lazy loading).

Comment: @Jankapunkt added the document structure to OP, because structure.length > commentLines.allowed. It's pretty much required to load instantly as I'm required to manipulate all data from afformentioned structure to use in visualizations. I let the client do all the JS / D3 summing and feed the processed data to the graphs. That way, I could use the "RAW" data in multiple visuals in different ways.

Comment: I mean I guess lazy-loading could work, but no clue how I'd go about it. If there is any other option to deal with this, I'm all ears.

Comment: I suspected this. You document is a huge summary of documents. You could easily decouple this data and make it 1900 documents that can be loaded lazy instead of one huge query. Since you load 40MB your users will have to wait anyway. But then you would be able to have many (but smaller) queries and therefore keep your server 'calm' in terms of memory usage.

Comment: I have no idea how this "decoupling" would work, but aside from that I'm running a client-side data modifier which needs all the documents before it can process the data. It does some nesting & summing stuff and I'd assume lazy-loading would mean I'd have to force it to wait for all the documents to come in one at a time. (I'm not using the raw data points for the visuals, only processed data. So all that data gets modified to calculate a, for instance, line graph with 4 lines of data)

Comment: @Jankapunkt could you share an example of your setup?

Comment: I think you need to do the aggregation on the server, where it has easy access to the data. Trying to send 40MB to the client is going to cause you problems anyway

Comment: Still considering the aggregation approach, but taking a different direction for the short term as I don't feel confident enough in doing the aggregation stuff yet. Altered the client-side fetches which were set up wrong (boy I feel stupid), forcing too much data to be transferred anyway. I only need 1 (the latest) item of `DataSet1`, and that DataSet is responsible for over 80% of 1 document. For now I should have some wiggle room to play with but I'll definately keep an eye on aggregation if by any chance I figure out a way to deal with it.